# Setting Twilio SMS url to blank via REST API

Tags: twilio

I want to disable SMS for a phone number that has been ported into my Twilio account.  When a number is ported into the account Twilio assigns a demo URL.  How can I blank that URL out via the REST API?  When I try via the REST API there is validation on the SMS URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`SmsUrl` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications#instance) to `nil`:

```
require 'twilio-ruby' 

# put your own credentials here 
account_sid = your_account_sid
auth_token = your_auth_token 

# set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API 
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token 

@client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.get('the phone number ID').update({
'SmsUrl' => nil
})
```